# Why can't I pipe to parallel?

Tags: command-line, pipe, gnu-parallel

I have been trying to pipe this command

`tail -n +$line $FILENAME`

to this command

`parallel -a $FILENAME -k --block $sub --pipe-part "cut -d ' ' -f1" | sponge $FILENAME`

And the resulting command is as follows:

`tail -n +$line $FILENAME | parallel -k --block $sub --pipe-part --eta --progress "$cut -d ' ' -f1 | sponge $FILENAME`

I also tried the same thing with --pipe instead of --pipe-part

Why is this command emptying my file completely? How does piping work with the parallel command?

Comment: Because the input must be `seek()`-able when you use `--pipepart`.

Comment: What error message do you get, or what happens incorrectly?

Comment: @JeffSchaller the file gets emptied

Comment: @SatoKatsura seek()-able? I also tried it with --pipe btw.

Comment: is this running in a script?  If so you must set job control using `set -m`

Comment: @val0x00ff the thing is that the same command is working inside the script when I am not piping to it

Comment: From the manual: _--pipepart has a few limitations: The file must be a normal file or a block device (technically it must be seekable) and must be given using -a or ::::. The file cannot be a pipe or a fifo as they are not seekable._

Comment: @SatoKatsura but --pipe didn't work either.

Comment: If that's your only issue, why don't you just use a temporary file?